# Serverless Enable CORS

Tags: cors, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, aws-amplify

How do I enable CORS in Serverless?

I keep getting the following error msg while calling my lambda function.

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I've searched everywhere, and I still couldn't figure out how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Here is my setup:

My Python handler, tested with `serverless invoke local`

```
def main(event, context):
    ...operations with pandas...

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'headers': {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': True
        },
        'body': json.dumps(response),
    }
```

My serverless.yml

```
functions:
  main:
    handler: handler.main
    events:
      - http:
          path: dashboard
          method: get
          authorizer: aws_iam
          cors: true
```

My frontend, a React app. The API call is made with aws-amplify:

```
try{
  const myInit = {
    body: JSON.stringify(this.props.session),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  };
  const calculation = await API.get("clearly", "/dashboard", myInit)
  console.log(calculation);
} catch(e) {
  ...
}
```

Thanks!

Edit:

While I was trying to enable CORS manually in API Gateway, I got this `Invalid Response status code specified` error msg.
[Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQncf.png)

Answer (score 1):

Have you created OPTIONS method with the mock integration type to return the response headers like these

Access-Control-Allow-Methods
Access-Control-Allow-Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Just reference ( https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html )